# Why HTML does not play video automatically?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, video

I followed the tutorial to start show video, right after it is loaded. But it does not work now. Why?

```
<video
  width="100%"
  minHeight="100%"
  autoplay
  muted
  loop
  playsinline
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    center: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: -1,
  }}
>
  <source
    src={`http://ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${props.urlPrefix}-intro.mp4`}
    type="video/mp4"
  />
</video>
```

Comment: You're a 28k answerer so I don't want to be stupid in asking if you considered making the video a background in it's Parent so that other stuff can be placed normally above it?

Comment: Any warnings/errors in your devtool console? Also, could you add the actual HTML your react app generates so we can _see what the browser sees_? Since your video is hostet in an S3 bucket you maybe could actually add your problem as a runnable snippet ?

Comment: Is it not autoplaying everywhere or just on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be the source link, have you tried another video link?

Comment: This is not a definitive answer and probably not the problem here.